# Rails Multiple Polymorphic Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In my program, I have the tables Riders, Drivers, and Preferences.

Each Rider and Driver has their own set of ranked preferences of the other model. (Eg. `Rider1` has preferences favoring `[Driver1, Driver2, Driver3]` in that order)

```rb
class Rider
has_many :preferences, as: :preferable -> { order(position: :asc) }

# has other stuff like a rider's current driver (if they have one), etc.

end

class Driver
has_many :preferences, as: :preferable -> { order(position: :asc) }

# other things like a driver's car (and current passengers)

end

class Preference
belongs_to :preferable, polymorphic: true

# tbd what to put here

end
```

Because a `Preference` can belong to either a `Driver` or `Rider`, I thought a polymorphic association would be best.

The Preferences table is planned to be a single table that will hold all the preferences of all riders and drivers.

Everything seems to *look* okay, except the fact that each Preference needs to point to a specific `person`.

But I'm stumped as to how best to go about that. It seems that `person` will have to be **either** a Rider or a Driver. And so it seems to be another polymorphic association.

Except, adding something to `Preference` like `belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true` leaves me wondering, what type of respective relationship I'd put down in `Rider` and `Driver`? Like a `has_one` or `has_many` doesn't seem to quite make sense to me imo.

This is the functionality in which I'm aiming to accomplish:

1. All riders or drivers should have preferences, and each preference should point to specific person (of the opposite type).
2. Preferences should be bi-directional. If a rider's state changes, in each driver's preferences, that rider will stay up-to-date to those changes
3. Fetch a driver or rider preferences, and check a current property about a specific preferred entity.

- Such as looking through a driver's preferences, and checking if their first preference already has a driver (something like `rider1.is_taken?`)

I'm imagining seeding to be something like (slight pseudo code):

```rb
max = Rider.create!( 
  name: "Max",
  address: "Pike Place Market"
)

jacob = Driver.create!(
  name: "Jacob",
  address: "Seattle",
  total_space: 3
)

leo = Driver.create!(
  name: "Leo",
  address: "New York",
  total_space: 1
)

# This would create preferences [Jacob, Leo] for Max 
# such that he'd prefer Jacob over Max.
Preference.create!(
  preferable: max,
  person: jacob
);

Preference.create!(
  preferable: max,
  person: leo
);
```

Any thoughts on how to handle Rider/Driver preferences? Is it another polymorphic association? If so, what do I then put in the other models besides `Preference`?

Maybe I'm also structuring this in a poor way, and if that's the case, I'm absolutely open to hearing different ideas.

Comment: Which attributes are supposed to be in the preferences model?

Comment: Solved this earlier, but I just needed two polymorphic associations on my `Preference` model. One for the individual who is the preferrer and the other who is the target of the preference (the preferable). Answer posted below!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out polymorphic associations did work out!

Each `Preference` has a `preferrer` and `preferable` and both attributes can either be a `Rider` or `Driver`.

```
class Preference < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :preferrer, polymorphic: true, required: true
  belongs_to :preferable, polymorphic: true, required: true
end
```

Creating a `Preference` for a `Rider` would go like this:

```
someRider = Rider.create!(...)
someDriver = Driver.create!(...)

Preference.create!(
  preferrer: someRider,
  preferable: someDriver
)
```

Then I opted to order the preferences for each individual by `created_at` (this is just a small hobby project).